# How to convert following data to column in format given below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to convert following data to column in excel (any formula or method)?

I have a column with randon numbers as below

```
0
10
25
45
0
25
45
0
45
```

i want to convert above to like this

```
0     10     25     45     
0      0     25     45    
0      0      0     45
```

how to convert above in excel with formula or any shortcut way?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel 365, try this as a spill formula:

```
=IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A6))>ROW(A1:A6),TRANSPOSE(A1:A6),0)
```

[image]

You could use Byrow and Textjoin if you wished to put them all in a single column:

```
=BYROW(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A6))>ROW(A1:A6),TRANSPOSE(A1:A6),0),LAMBDA(array,TEXTJOIN(" ",,array)))
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

My formula in cell B1 is:

```
=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3&" "&A4&" "&A5&" "&A6
```

But if you have Excel365 probably you may benefit from [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Formula in cell B2 is:
`=SUBSTITUTE(B1;A2;"0";1)`

Drag down and you will get the output desired.